# How to put a global character in a rule so that it can be replaced by any coefficient when i use this rule?

Tags: pattern-matching, fourier-analysis

I have the following rules

```
rule1=FourierCosTransform[e[x], x, p]-> eF[p,q,s]; 
rule2=FourierCosTransform[u[x], x, p]-> uF[p,q,s];
rule3=FourierSinTransform[\[Theta][x], x, p]-> \[Theta]F[p,q,s];
rule4=FourierSinTransform[v[x], x, p]-> vF[p,q,s];
rule={rule1,rule2,rule3,rule4}
```

and i try to apply it to the equation:

```
eq=s (1 + s b) u[x] + s (1 + s b) v[x] + s \[Theta][x] + s^2 b e[x]
```

I used:

```
Distribute[FourierCosTransform[eq],x,p]/.rule
```

but it does not work? Is there any global character I can use instead of the coefficients of the functions? How can I make it works?

Comment: You might want to look at [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) and the [guide to Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Patterns.html). If this is not what you're after, could you explain a bit more what you expect the output to be and what you mean by "global character"?

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answer. I expect the following results:      s(1+sb) uF[p,q,s]+s(1+sb) vF[p,q,s]+s \thetaF[p,q,s]+s^2b eF[p,q,s]                and by global character I mean that which I can write in the rule and then replaced by the coeffiecients like  s(1+sb) or s^2b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can achieve what you want with [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html):

Since `FourierCosTransform` and `FourierSinTransform` are both linear, we can first add a rule that pull out factors:

```
rule5 = (h:FourierCosTransform|FourierSinTransform)[a_ f_, x_, p_] 
        :> a h[f, x, p] /; FreeQ[a, x];
```

What this does: It matches anything that has `Head` `FourierCosTransform` or `FourierSinTransform` (and calls it `h`) and an argument that looks like a product. It the pulls out the factor `a`, but only if `a` does not depend on `x`. (**Update**: this [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html), `/;` for short, is needed as otherwise things like `FourierCosineTransform[f[x]g[x],x,p]` are replaced with `f[x] FourierCosineTransform[g[x],x,p]`, which is clearly wrong)

Adding this rule to `rule` and appyling it repeatedly (using [`ReplaceRepeated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceRepeated.html) or `//.` for short), we get:

```
In[1]:=  Distribute[FourierCosTransform[eq, x, p]] //. rule
Out[1]:= b s^2 eF[p, q, s] + s (1 + b s) FourierCosTransform[v[x], x, p] + 
         s FourierCosTransform[\[Theta][x], x, p] + s (1 + b s) uF[p, q, s]
```

As you can see, this does nothing with two of the terms, but I'm not quite sure how you want to get there (given that your rules are for `FourierSinTransform`).

You might also want to generalize the other rules to allow for differently named variables, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try it

Comment: OK. It works well. But what this part    " /; FreeQ[a, x];"  used for? I used rule5 without it.

Comment: I apply the Cos rule it works well and it does not work for those terms defined by the Sin rule? I should apply a general rule valid to apply for the Cos and Sin Fourier transform in the same equation!

Comment: I updated the answer with an explanation of the `/;` part. As for the `FourierSinTransform`: As I wrote in my answer, I don't see how you want to apply rules 3 and 4 to the expression at hand: You specify a rule for `FourierSinTransfrom[v[x], x, p]`, but the expression contains only `FourierCosTransform[v[x], x, p]`. Without additional assumptions, I don't think you can do anything.